# Get SQLite values in config() using Ionic/Angular

Tags: angularjs, sqlite, cordova, ionic-framework

I use the plugin Cordova-sqlite-storage (https://github.com/litehelpers/Cordova-sqlite-storage) in order to read and write to sqlite in my ionic/angular app:. In addition, I use the $stateProvider in ionic to decide which states to push to the navigation stack:

```
var app = angular.module('media_reminder');
app.config(function ($stateProvider) {...});
```

Now I have a tutorial view which I only want to view if the sqlite db doesn't contain a flag "tutorialShown=1".

Unfortunately in cordova plugins I have to wait for the deviceready event. Is there any way to use it in the config() method already? Or how can I solve this problem in some other way?

An alternative to use would be localStorage. But as you know this one is volatile, i.e. could be removed by iOS/Android :(

Thanks in advance.

Bye!

Comment: use a `resolve` on that state. Not really clear what you had in mind to do in config

Comment: $stateProvider is configured in config():

$stateProvider
    .state('tutorial', {
        url: '/tutorial',
        templateUrl: 'app/tutorial/tutorial.template.html',
        controller: 'TutorialCtrl'
    })

$urlRouterProvider.otherwise(tutorialShown ? '/' : '/tutorial'); // pseudocode

Comment: your app needs to wait for deviceready to use this plugin , but one thing you can do is just remove your $urlRouterProvider.otherwise from config and use $state.go() in device ready based on that sqllite flag .

Comment: This was exactly the hint I needed. Thanks!